# Why a while statement doesn't work after a do while?

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

I'm confused about the working of the order of do while and a while. My inicial question is to ask to the user to write a number. If the number is higher than 7 it should display that number and count back down to 0. I'm still studying but I'm quiet stuck on this at the moment so it would be great if someone could explain on how this works and the logics behind it!

What I have now is:

```
int num = 0;
        int b = 0;
        do{

            System.out.println("Por favor introduce un numero:");
            num = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

            if(num > 7){
                System.out.println("Tu numero es mayor a 7");

            }else if (num <= 7) {
                System.out.println("Tu numero es menor o igual a 7");
            }

          }while(num < 7);

            while(num < 7){
                 System.out.println(num);
                 num++;
            }
```

I understand that this won't work because of the statement being fullfilt when you pick a number higher as 7 and it just returns "Tu numero es mayor a 7".
BUT i found out that if i use another Do While it works and counts down to 0 (see below):

```
int num = 0;
        int b = 0;
        do{

            System.out.println("Por favor introduce un numero:");
            num = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

            if(num > 7){
                System.out.println("Tu numero es mayor a 7");

            }else if (num <= 7) {
                System.out.println("Tu numero es menor o igual a 7");
            }



        }while(num < 7);

        do{
        System.out.println(num);
        num--; }
        while(b<=num);

    }          

}
```

With another Do while it will show me the count down to 0 I understand in a sense that the int num got the value of the input of the user but why won't this work with a while statement ? Could i incorporate the while statement in the Do While ? I've also tried to put it within the Do While statement but it's completely ignored??

Comment: are you asking how to use another while loop to check if the number is above zero? And if it isn't decrease it after the user input

Comment: The conditions in your first example and second example are completely different. What is `b`? One loop just expects a number not to fulfill a condition it just fulfilled. he other performs operations on a number and tests it after those changes.

Comment: After the first do while loop, `num` is `7`.

Comment: After a `do-while` loop its condition is false, otherwise it would still be running. A subsequent `while` *using the same condition* will therefore never execute. A `while` using a different condition may.

Answer (score 0):

Cycle `do while` performs check in the end, which means that cycle body is always executed at least once. But for cycle `while` condition is checked in the beginning, so body is newer executed if the condition is not satisfied from the start.

You can understand your situation better if you use debugging, but in short:

1. First cycle is executed while the condition is satisfied. So you exit the cycle when `num < 7` returns `false`. So you exit when it's `7`, `8` or greater.
2. Then second cycle executes at least once only when exactly the same condition `num < 7` is `true`. But it's `false` - otherwise you don't exit the previous cycle. So if `num` is still `8`, you skip the cycle altogether.
3. So second cycle is always skipped. Unless you correct the condition. Or nest the cycles. Or modify `num` between the cycles. Or invent your own option.

In second example second cycle contains a completely different condition `b<=num`, which is `true` anyway, unless you redefine `b`. But even if you use `num < 7` condition but keep `do while` cycle, cycle's body will still execute at least once. It's just the way this type of cycle works.